# How can I add locations to iCal events?

Tags: calendar, geolocation, maps

The OS X Calendar app will suggest locations as I enter text into the location field of an appointment; but in practice, it does a terrible (technically, an astonishingly terrible) job of suggesting things, proposing locations that are continents away, or clearly obscure, wile missing locations that are prominent, nearby, or that I have visited before.

Is there a way, other than entering a full address, to improve the suggestions for locations provided in Calendar events? Is there a way to expand the list of suggestions or provide the search information in a format that will produce better results?